# Character variables default to factor in R

Tags: r

All the sources indicate that the character variables `name` and `gender` in this data frame from startSalary.csv are to be categorized as factors.

```
name    salary  gender    
Anne    75000   F    
David   70000   M    
Cindy   55000   F    
Mark    65000   M    
Patrick 64000   M
```

When I read it as follows:

```
df1 <- read.csv("startSalary.csv")
str(df1)

data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
$ name  : chr  "Anne" "David" "Cindy" "Mark" ...
$ salary: int  75000 70000 55000 65000 64000
$ gender: chr  "F" "M" "F" "M" ...
```

R categorizes these variables as characters, not the default categorization as factor.
I know I could read the data as

```
df2 <- read.csv("startSalary.csv",stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

for R to categorize them as factors.
Why my R codes are not categorizing them as factors, which is the default?
I have not used any `options()` function. Have I done a global change in defaults without knowing about it?

Thanks.

Comment: The default changed with `R 4.0.0`. Now, stringsAsFactors = FALSE by default

Comment: Add this line at the begin of your code `options(stringsAsFactors = T)`

Comment: Thank you.    
This information "The default changed with R 4.0.0. Now, stringsAsFactors = FALSE by default" explains the reason.